# On PC restart, Android studio (4.0) shows all "red" for all android / java classes

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, plugins

Recently restarted computer and opened up existing project and Android Studio shows "red" for all android and java classes.

Builds fine - details below.  (Even introduced a compilation error which the build detects just fine; restore and builds OK.)

Tried (with no effect):

- restarting
- invalidate cache / restart
- opened another past project which had been fine and same error.
- Trying to use menu "File | Settings" has no response.

Thanks for any ideas...

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 1 s 15 ms
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:processDebugResources
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dexBuilderDebug
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
> Task :app:packageDebug
> Task :app:assembleDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 10s
21 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 14 up-to-date
```

1 of 1000s of editor "Cannot resolve symbol":

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Turns out a plugin update can cause Studio to not initialize properly.  The `idea.log` file (located in `<user folder>/.AndroidStudio4.0/system/log` shows the error repeating continuously and likely prevented Studio to continue:

```
2020-06-17 20:07:22,043 [  97867]  ERROR - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - Android Studio 4.0  Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223 
2020-06-17 20:07:22,043 [  97867]  ERROR - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - JDK: 1.8.0_242-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2020-06-17 20:07:22,044 [  97868]  ERROR - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - OS: Windows 10 
2020-06-17 20:07:22,044 [  97868]  ERROR - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - Plugin to blame: CSV Plugin version: 2.12.0 
2020-06-17 20:07:22,044 [  97868]  ERROR - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - Last Action: CheckForUpdate 
2020-06-17 20:07:22,044 [  97868]  ERROR - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - While loading class net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv.CsvFileTypeOverrider: net/seesharpsoft/intellij/plugins/csv/CsvFileTypeOverrider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 [Plugin: net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv] 
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: While loading class net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv.CsvFileTypeOverrider: net/seesharpsoft/intellij/plugins/csv/CsvFileTypeOverrider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 [Plugin: net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv]
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClassInsideSelf(PluginClassLoader.java:223)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.tryLoadingClass(PluginClassLoader.java:167)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:75)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
```

**The offending plugin is CSV Plugin version 2.12.0** and evidently is compiled for a later version JDK which can't be supported.

Deleting the plugin folder from:

```
<user>/.AndroidStudio4.0/config/plugins/<offending plugin folder>
```

fixes the issue.

The error is logged to the idea.log continuously and results a log rotation and each log file is 10MB.  It is not at all obvious this is happening in the background - the only visible symptom is the "red" and things like "Settings..." does not work.

Comment: I tried deleting the plugin directory but still, it's not working. Do have any suggestion? @Andy

Comment: Look at the log file mentioned and see if any errors are shown - look for repeating errors which may prevent studio from starting.

Comment: I have the same error that you are using in your answer.  diagnostic.PluginException.

Answer (score 2):

**For Ubuntu users**

1. go to `home`
2. press `ctrl+h` to show hidden folder `.local`
3. now go to `.local` folder
4. you will find the `share` folder, go inside the `share` folder
5. Find `Google` and go to the `Android Studio 4.1` folder and Delete the plugin folder that causing the error.(in my case it was csv) 
    **OR**
   Delete the whole `Google` folder
6. Close `Android Studio` and Reopen
7. **Voila !!!**

**NOTE:** To find which plugin causing the error. You can check the repeated errors in the Android Studio log file.

**Help** -> **Show Log File** -> **idea.log**

In my case, I found this.

```
    com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: While loading class net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv.CsvFileTypeOverrider:
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/seesharpsoft/intellij/plugins/csv/CsvFileTypeOverrider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and also could not open the SDK anymore.
My solution (for Windows) in the folder:

```
C:\Users\xxxxAppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins\.
```

Delete the folders `CSV Plugin` and `Rainbow CSV`, after that everything worked again.

Comment: This solved the problem on my system running windows 10. Mate, thank you very much!