# Android studio 4.0 editor window is gone

Tags: android, code-editor, android-studio-4.0

I'm using Android studio v 4.0 on windows 10 (1909) build. Every thing was working fine till last evening my code editor window just disappeared.

I'tried followings

- Restart & invalidate cache
- Check for updates
- Reset default layout (shift+F12) [window -> Restore Default Layout]
- Tried Dragging file into center to open (editor never appears but breadcrumb updates for each file selected or opened screenshot given below

[image]

Many other components are also effected like

- Logcat showing nothing
- Event Log showing nothing
- Build & Sync showing nothing

One more strange thing is I'm unable to open settings [File -> Settings] (it shows nothing)

[image: Android Studio 4.0 code editor window gone]

Here is the about section of my installed android studio
[image: Android Studio 4.0]

idea.log1 contains this exception

```
2020-06-27 12:26:01,693 [5987243]  ERROR - enapi.editor.impl.SettingsImpl - Error determining tab size 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.SettingsImpl.getTabSize(SettingsImpl.java:377)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.ex.util.EditorUtil.getTabSize(EditorUtil.java:342)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.view.EditorView.getTabSize(EditorView.java:547)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.view.LogicalPositionCache.reset(LogicalPositionCache.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.view.EditorView.reinitSettings(EditorView.java:344)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.<init>(EditorImpl.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorFactoryImpl.createEditor(EditorFactoryImpl.java:200)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorFactoryImpl.createViewer(EditorFactoryImpl.java:170)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ConsoleViewUtil.setupConsoleEditor(ConsoleViewUtil.java:56)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.deprecated.ProgressStep.<init>(ProgressStep.java:61)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.VmWizard$SetupProgressStep.<init>(VmWizard.java:132)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.VmWizard$VmPath.init(VmWizard.java:251)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:98)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:233)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.VmWizard.<init>(VmWizard.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.install.VmInstallListener.lambda$statusChanged$0(VmInstallListener.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$1.run(LaterInvocator.java:154)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:441)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:407)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:908)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:781)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1077)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:708)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:433)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.doShow(DialogWrapper.java:1698)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.android.tools.idea.updater.UpdateInfoDialog$1.actionPerformed(UpdateInfoDialog.java:79)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6550)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6315)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4899)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:908)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:846)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:778)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:687)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1077)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:708)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:433)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.doShow(DialogWrapper.java:1698)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.android.tools.idea.updater.SdkComponentSource.installUpdates(SdkComponentSource.java:108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker$showUpdateResult$runnable$3.invoke(UpdateChecker.kt:427)
    at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker$showUpdateResult$runnable$3.invoke(UpdateChecker.kt:55)
    at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker.showUpdateResult(UpdateChecker.kt:430)
    at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker.access$showUpdateResult(UpdateChecker.kt:55)
    at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker$doUpdateAndShowResult$1.run(UpdateChecker.kt:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:309)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:441)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:407)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:908)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:781)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
2020-06-27 12:26:01,696 [5987246]  ERROR - enapi.editor.impl.SettingsImpl - Android Studio 4.0  Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223 
2020-06-27 12:26:01,696 [5987246]  ERROR - enapi.editor.impl.SettingsImpl - JDK: 1.8.0_242-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2020-06-27 12:26:01,696 [5987246]  ERROR - enapi.editor.impl.SettingsImpl - OS: Windows 10
```

Comment: check your `idea.log` in `<user folder>/.AndroidStudio4.0/system/log` for errors.  Might be a bad plugin preventing studio from working properly.

Comment: @Andy you are right, its giving has log of error. can you help me fix that, i'm updating the question

Comment: General solution is to identify plugin (from log) and remove plugin folder: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62440387/2711811 .

Comment: `idea.log1 ` is a rotated file (rotates after 10MB) so you probably have many repeating errors - try searching on `PluginClassLoader` .  That trace doesn't look like a plugin error though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While going through logs found this.

```
ERROR - ij.psi.stubs.StubUpdatingIndex - Error indexing:jar://C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-29/android.jar!/android/media/midi/MidiDevice.class 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class name.kropp.intellij.makefile.psi.MakefileTypes
```

[@Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711811/andy) you were right, deleting following folders fixed the issue.

1. C:\Users\user.AndroidStudio4.0\config\plugins
2. C:\Users\user.AndroidStudio4.0\config\cache

Although on first start studio thrown an exception but on next restart every thing was fine

Answer (score 6):

I got this error in Android Studio IDE

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: TextHitInfo is out of range

and then my text editor windows was gone. Restart and clear caches did not help.

On Mac this restored my editor window:

1. go to `<Project-Folder>/.idea/`
2. **delete** `workspace.xml`
3. close and reopen project.

Comment: It really works for macOS.

Comment: This work for me today on Android Studio v2021.2.1 Mac OS