# How to fix android studio issue instead of a clean install?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been working on integrating .so files into my project. And suddenly my android studio stopped responding and showing this message `"High number of internal exceptions has been detected. This indicates a serious problem with the IDE. Please consider clean reinstall of Android Studio. If the problem persists, please report a bug by following the link below."`

I've tried these to solve the issue, but did not help.

1. I've invalidated cache and restarted android studio
2. I've removed all files what i added to cause the problem
3. Restart my mac
4. Opened different project, still the same issue happening
5. Updated the android studio to 4.0.1

I'm not able to open any files and SDK manager in android studio. If anyone has faced the issue, please kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer to [Android studio 4.0 editor window is gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62609701/android-studio-4-0-editor-window-is-gone).

Deleting the following folders fixed the issue for me.

```
...\.AndroidStudio4.0\config\plugins
...\.AndroidStudio4.0\config\cache
```

UPDATE: I believe it was one specific plugin I had downloaded that had been causing the problem. So watch out for that.